# How to group multiple text and buttons using bootstrap?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

Trying to group some buttons and a text field using bootstrap but it looks very strange. I checked many resources on internet but not helpful. For one button and text, it works perfect.

It's prefered to look like this:

[image]

But they look like this:

[image]

2 Buttons always drop down, whatever I tried.
I wonder if is it even possible to do it using Bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group btn-block">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <input type="button" value="-10" class="form-control">
   <input type="button" value="-1" class="form-control">
  </span>
  <input type="text" value="10" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <input type="button" value="+1" class="form-control">
   <input type="button" value="+10" class="form-control">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
  </span>
 </div>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I got it to work... I removed the spans and added a style with a width of 50px, but you could keep the spans, I just removed them to clear up some clutter... Adjust the width to your liking.

```
<div class="input-group btn-block">
        <input type="button" value="-10" class="form-control" style="width: 50px;">
        <input type="button" value="-1" class="form-control" style="width: 50px;">
        <input type="text" value="10" class="form-control" style="width: 50px;">
        <input type="button" value="+1" class="form-control" style="width: 50px;">
        <input type="button" value="+10" class="form-control" style="width: 50px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 50px;"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="width: 50px;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try the below code use `Input-group`

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="input-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">-10</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">-1</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">-10</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">-1</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle">
</i></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

See The Below Fiddle

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6mcxdjdr/39/)